# cd to real directory referenced my symbolic link

Tags: macos, unix

How can i cd into a symbolically linked directory but, when moving from there, doing it relatively to the *real* directory?

For example

```
dir_1
    link_to_dir_3 ->

..

dir_2
    dir_3
```

If I do `cd link_to_dir_3` and then `cd ..` I wanto tp go to `dir_2` and not `dir_1`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
cd `pwd -P`
cd ..
```

The first `cd` will take you from `dir_1/link_to_dir_3` to `dir_2/dir_3`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `readlink`:

```
cd $(readlink -n link)
```